# eine Frage wird geklärt, eine Lösung gefunden werden

Tags: grammar-identification, ellipsis

The Cambridge online German-English dictionary defines "etw. wird sich finden" as follows:

eine Frage wird geklärt, eine Lösung gefunden werden

I'd like to know whether the above can be paraphrased as "eine Frage wird geklärt **werden**, eine Lösung gefunden."

Comment: Yes, you can phrase it that way; the sentence is grammatically correct and in terms of meaning coherent. It is a stylistic choice. Both the original and your phrase are a bit mannerist or high-register.

Answer (score 2):

> Eine Frage wird geklärt, eine Lösung gefunden

entspräche von der Zeitform

> Etwas findet sich.

Da die erklärte Phrase aber auf die Zukunft verweist:

> Etwas wird sich finden.

verweist auch die Erklärung auf die Zukunft, also

> - Eine Frage wird geklärt werden.
> - Eine Lösung wird gefunden werden.

Diese zwei Beispiele kann man auch zu einem Satz verbinden:

> Eine Frage wird geklärt werden, eine Lösung wird gefunden werden.

Dies kann man abkürzen zu:

> - Eine Frage wird geklärt werden, eine Lösung wird gefunden.
> - Eine Frage wird geklärt werden, eine Lösung gefunden.
> - Eine Frage wird geklärt, eine Lösung gefunden werden.

Also ist die Antwort: Ja.

Mit

> Eine Frage wird geklärt, eine Lösung gefunden.

ginge dagegen der Verweis auf die Zukunft verloren.

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to know why you used the subjunctive forms "entspräche" and "ginge" in your answer.

Comment: This mixes tenses: Eine Frage wird geklärt werden, eine Lösung wird gefunden.

Comment: Die Variante "Eine Frage wird geklärt werden, eine Lösung wird gefunden [werden]" missfällt mir. Dass das zweite "werden" ausgelassen wird, fällt nicht auf, so dass der zweite Teil als Präsens verstanden würde. Das ist bei "Eine Frage wird geklärt [werden], eine Lösung [wird] gefunden werden" zwar eigentlich auch der Fall, aber diese, nennen wir es einmal: "chiastische Ellipse" verrät wenigstens im zweiten Teil, dass das "werden" (Hilfsverb des Passivs) am Ende zum "wird" (Hilfsverb des Futur) am Anfang gehört und damit umgekehrt das "wird" im ersten Teil nicht Hilfsverb des Passivs ist.

Comment: In *eine Frage wird geklärt, eine Lösung gefunden werden* the *werden* refers also to the first part of the sentence as in *eine Frage wird geklärt werden*. That's why they are in the same tense and the sentence works.